# How to make all my imports in a separete setup.py file then importing this file in main.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pip

I'm trying to make a setup script that will install needed python modules on machines that don't have it. so going with the recommended way of installing packages this is my `setup.py`

```
import subprocess
import sys
import importlib

required_packages = ["cryptography.fernet", "os", "pip"]
for package in required_packages:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(package)
        print("Imported {} successfully".format(package))
    except ImportError:
        subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
        print("Installed {} successfully".format(package))
```

and `main.py` as :

```
import setup
os.walk(".")   # cause an error
```

This way I have control about which modules have been installed and which not and then install them. the problem is that importing `setup.py in main.py` doesn't seem to import these packages in the global namespace of `main.py` so how can I make these two python files work as intended.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to make other users install packages you want. What if they're intentionally using an older version of a package for compatibility reasons? This could break their older code. Instead simply include `requirements.txt` with names and versions of required packages and users can then decide whether they want to create a separate venv for your package specifically.

Comment: @pavel I can't see how this could break their older code, as I try to include the required modules if ```ImportError``` occurs(so package is not installed) so I install it in the ```else```  statement right?.

Comment: This is a terrible idea. `os` is a built-in module. And how are you planning to install the `pip` from `required_packages`, when the code tries to use a pip installation to do that in the first place?

Comment: @wim yeah are absolutely right but i just added these as to illustrate the idea. anyway the above code wont install anything already installed (there is no harm ) so the above code will just loop through them without any actions

Comment: Wrong, it will attempt to install "os" from PyPI, which is exactly the kind of name-squatting that malicious code likes to do. If I saw a code trying to subprocess a pip install from within a `setup.py` file I would delete and blacklist that app immediately!

Comment: @wim I think i missed that can you tell me how it will reinstall ```os```

Comment: In this case `pypi.org/project/os` doesn't (currently) exist, but there have been [several cases](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2017/09/19/pypi-python-repository-hit-by-typosquatting-sneak-attack/) where fake names such as "setup-tools", "urllib", "telnet", "bzip", ["python3-dateutil"](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/984) were uploaded with malicious code. If you tried to `pip install os` there might appear a nasty surprise one day.

Comment: @wim yes but in my example this will require the firing of the ```except ImportError:``` which will only fire when ```try: import os``` raise an error which is very unlikely to happen but if it happens then there is a problem right? and thanks a lot didn't know that I can download viruses from ```pypi ```one day always thought they have pretty much safe code but it seems to happen quite not rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main.py` file should import the `setup.py` file like this:

```py
import setup
__import__('setup', globals={"__name__": __name__})
```

I would consider renaming your `setup.py` file to something like `install_packages.py` as 'setup' may conflict with previously assigned values - example:

```py
import install_packages
__import__('install_packages', globals={"__name__": __name__})
```

Comment: this seems to half work since only modules imported as ```import something``` in ```setup.py``` are the only ones that work main while other packages like ```cryptography``` doesn't seems to get imported as it seems to not be in the global namespace of main.

Comment: Updated the answer, hope it helps :)

Comment: Why do you import it twice?